# Problem with Firebase Authentication not found

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm building an IOS 17 app and i'm using firebase for the authentication of the users.
I created a database and copy pasted the link for the firebase package in XCode 15; the installation went smoothly without any error but when i went to create an authentication view model it tells me that "FirebaseAuth is not in the scope" and i can't seem to find the reason why since i can see it in my packages list.

I tried reinstalling the package twice but i don't know what else to do, any help?

Comment: It's hard to say a word unless you tell us under what class you see the error message. Besides, what you have done so far is just to incorporate into your project the Firebase package, which contains what?

Comment: @ElTomato i copy pasted this link: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk (that firebase gives you when you set up a database) into "add packaging dependecies". It contains firebase auth so i don't know what i'm doing wrong

Comment: Do you have an account with Firebase Console?